# How to resolve error in net 6: Could not load type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile from assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iformfile, typeloadexception

I have this error when I run the project:

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=6.0.0.0`

I use dot net 6.0

These are my dependencies:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I don't know what's the problem!

I Tried different versions of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features' packages, but the problem is exists and I search for solution, but it wasn't helpful!

Please sb help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `<FrameworkReference>` element to your project file: [target-aspnetcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

```
<ItemGroup>
 <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 ...
</ItemGroup>
```

And check .`csproj` of project. The first line should be as follows as one of these:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Or:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```